# Messed up .bash_profile in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

While making some configurations to include `JAVA_HOME` in the environment, I created the file `.bash_profile`, updated it with `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables. While updating the `PATH` variable, I forgot to include `PATH:` in the command `EXPORT PATH='PATH:/usr/...` . Then, I ran the command `source /.bash_profile` and it messed up everything. Now I cannot find the basic commands too in the `PATH` and shows error in commands like `vi` , `ls` etc.

I now want everything to be restored back to the previous state. Please helm me !

Comment: So how does your .bash_profile look right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted your `.bash_profile` to look like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/another/path/to/something"
```

this will append your new path to the existing one (The `$` substitutes a variable name with its contents). Also, I recommend using the file `~/.bashrc` for values to be loaded at every bash invocation. (Be sure to make a backup)

So, have you tried turning it on and off? After logging in again, your `PATH` should look normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can call commands with their full path - `/usr/bin/<command>` or `/bin/<command>` usually.

Also you can export a new PATH yourself interactively:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
```

Also when you edit your `.bash_profile` you'll want `export PATH=$PATH:<new path>`

Comment: Thank! it helped. Can you let me know what does `source` command do?

Comment: See `$ help source`: `source FILENAME ARGUMENTS` Execute commands from a file in the current shell. Read and execute commands from `FILENAME` in the current shell.  The entries in `$PATH` are used to find the directory containing `FILENAME`.  If any `ARGUMENTS` are supplied, they become the positional parameters when `FILENAME` is executed.